# Root of trig polynomial

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

I'm trying to find the roots of this function:

$f(x)=a x^2 \sin(x) + b \left(x \cos(x) - \sin(x)\right)=0$

is there a name for this type of function? Is anything known about finding the roots? Ideally, a solution for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ would be great!

Comment: This equation contains the variable $x$ both inside and outside transcendental functions, so one should expect that there is no closed-form general solution for general $a,b$. That said, by inspection we can see that $x = 0$ is always a solution.

Comment: can a series be found for the solution?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=a x^2 \sin(x) + b \left(x \cos(x) - \sin(x)\right)=0
$

If $a=0$,
this is
$x\cos(x)=\sin(x)$
or
$x = \tan(x)$
which has been discussed here before.
This has an infinite number of roots.

If $a \ne 0$,
dividing by $a$
this becomes
$x^2 \sin(x) + c (x \cos(x) - \sin(x))=0
$.

Dividing by sin,
this becomes
$x^2 + c x/ \tan(x) - c=0
$.
This doesn't look promising.

I'll stop here.